# Material3 replacement for PrimarySurface

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-dark-theme

I've started to replace styles with the new Material3 ones (Material You) which are present in the latest Material Design Components library. However, I don't see a replacement for `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface` (a style that handles dark mode better by not using the primary color, which looks to bright). There's `Widget.Material3.Toolbar`, `Widget.Material3.Toolbar.Surface` and `Widget.Material3.Toolbar.OnSurface` but I don't think any of them is a replacement.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface` style is just a combination of  `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary` and `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface` styles for light and dark mode.

That means this style uses colorPrimary in light mode and colorSurface in dark mode.

In the Material 3 (Material you) , the default background color for the toolbar is changed from colorPrimary to colorSurface.

You can always customize these material 3 themes according to your preference.

Comment: Yes, after my question I noted that the idea now is not to use the primary color as the background in top bars. Thanks!

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo Can you please answer my question ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76144823/how-to-customize-toolbar-in-material3