# How to customize toolbar in material3?

Tags: xml, material-ui, material3

I'm using material3 for my app. I want to customize the look of the toolbar. This is the toolbar

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/ToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="@string/app_name"/>
```

I tried defining styles in themes and using themes in the toolbar but it's not working fine for me. If icons are white popup menu is something different. If pop-menu is okay icons are not white color. So I want toolbar material with white icons and background #1d95fe and The popup menu background color should be white and the text should be black. All I want this using material 3.

I'm using the base theme as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set background attribute to your Toolbar, e.g.:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```